# Correlation amomg cohomology of a group $G$ and singular coohomology of its classifying space $BG$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

Assume that $G$ is a finite group and let's denote by $BG$ its classifying space. Then we know that we can construct the cohomology $H^{*}(G ; M)$ with (local) coefficients, for a $G$-module $M$, in the usual way via a projective resolution for $\mathbb{Z}$ and afterwards applying the contravariant functor $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(-,M)$ we obtain a cochain complex and its $n$-cohomology is denoted by $H^{n}(G ; M)$ and it is called the $n$-cohomology of $G$.

Now, recently I read in Adem's, Milgram book "Cohomology of finite groups" that the cohomology of a group is given by $H^{*}(G ; M)= H^{*}(BG ; M) $, whereas by $H^{*}(BG ; M) $ we denote the singular cohomology of $BG$. I do understand that in this book these guys are doing algebraic topology, so needs a more geometrical flavour upon the notion of cohomology of groups.

However, because these two "different" approaches must somehow to be equivalent this means that the first approach is isomorphic with the second one. So, can you explain me please how do we prove that the $n$-cohomology group of $G$ is isomorphic with the $n$-singular cohomology group of the classifying space $BG$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the covering space $p_G:EG\rightarrow BG$, let $Sing(BG)$ be the singular complex of $BG$ you can lift it to $EG$ and obtain a complex $Sing(EG)$ on which $G$ acts, remark that the (co)homology of $Sing(EG)$ is trivial since $EG$ is contractible. Thus, endowed with the action of $G$, $Sing(EG)$ defines a free resolution of $G$.

Comment: +1 - and it's a ${\mathbb Z}G$-free resolution by the uniqueness of liftings along coverings.

Comment: thank you very much, so this resolution of $G$ is the "same" resolution as the above that I mentioned?